# Wortherkunft von Landgut

Tags: etymology

Ich möchte gern die GENAUE Herkunft des Kompositums Landgut wissen *(bitte keine Übersetzung ins Englische, Latein oder in eine andere Sprache. Danke!)*
Das Wort lässt sich zergliedern in

a) Grundwort: das Gut

b) Bestimmungswort: das Land

Das Problem: Sowohl **Land** als auch **Gut** haben laut Duden und Wahrig mehrere mögliche Bedeutungen, und irgendwann in der Spätantike/im Mittelalter entstand daraus das Kompositum Landgut.

Welche(r) Deutschmuttersprachler(in) könnte mir bitte aus seiner/ihrer persönlichen Sprachperspektive erklären, welche der mehreren möglichen Bedeutungen von a) und b) jeweils bei der Prägung des Begriffes zum Spiel kam?

Zum Beispiel: Heißt da "Land" das Gegenstück zum Stadt- o. Dorfgebiet? Oder ist es gleichbedeutend mit "Ländereien"? Und wie steht es mit "Gut"?

Ich verstehe sehr wohl was ein Landgut im heutigen Sinne ist, und weiß eins treffend zu erkennen, sehe aber mehr als eine Möglichkeit für die Herkunft des Kompositums **Land-Gut**, und da hilft Wikipedia nicht weiter ...

Danke im Voraus für jegliches Kommentar.

Comment: Beim Duden-Eintrag zu [Landgut](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Landgut) steht unter "Bedeutung": Gut (2) - also von den 4 unter Gut aufgelisteten Bedeutungen ist die 2. heranzuziehen. Reicht das für "Gut"?

Comment: Erstmal nur als Kommentar: es gibt auch den Begriff [Stadtgut](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Stadtgut) - eventuell deutet das darauf hin, dass zwischen Gütern auf dem Land und in der Stadt unterschieden werden sollte.

Comment: Zu beachten auch *Hofgut*, *Gutshof* und *Gut* (letzteres als Synonym für "Landgut").

Comment: Niemand kann Dir das aus seiner persönlichen Sprachperspektive erklären, denn niemand von uns hat im Mittelalter gelebt. Deshalb gibt es ja Sprach*wissenschaft*.

Comment: Ähnlich wie [Eintopf](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Eintopf) ist eine genaue Herkunft nicht klärbar, egal wie stark man sich das wünscht.

Answer (score 2):

Ich glaube nicht, dass man sich hier nur auf die Etymologie stützen kann, weil eine Komplikation dazu kommt: Bei zusammengesetzten Substantiven kann der erste Teil alle mögliche Funktionen haben; das ergibt sich eher durch Konvention als durch die überlieferten Bedeutungen der Bestandteile.

Der [Meyer von 1885-92](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/schlagwort.html?wort=Landgut&werk=Meyers) (als die verschiedenen Gutsformen fast noch relevant waren) definiert:

> **Landgut**, ein mehr oder minder ausgedehnter, zum Betrieb einer Landwirtschaft (Ackerbau, Viehzucht) vereinigter Grundbesitz mit Wohn- und Wirtschaftsgebäuden. Auf einem L. werden oft auch landwirtschaftliche Nebengewerbe betrieben (Branntweinbrennerei, Bierbrauerei, Stärkefabrikation, Ziegelei, Kalkbrennerei, Gipsbrennerei, Runkelrübenzuckerfabrikation etc.); aber für den Begriff L. ist wesentlich, daß diese Gewerbe nur Nebengewerbe sind und der **eigentliche Landwirtschaftsbetrieb der Hauptzweck des Gutes** ist. Die Unterschiede von Allodial-, Lehns-, Ritter-, Frei-, Schulzen-, Fron-, Haus- und Bauerngütern etc. haben in der neuern Zeit mehr und mehr ihre eigentliche und ursprüngliche Bedeutung verloren, seitdem die neuern Ablösungsgesetze die grundherrlichen Lasten beseitigt und die mannigfachen mehr oder minder beschränkten Besitz- und Nutzungsrechte, besonders an Bauerngütern, in freies Eigentum verwandelt haben und anderseits die mit dem Besitz mancher Güter verbundenen Vorrechte aufgehoben worden sind.

Hier und in den verwandten Stichwörtern finden sich interessante Hinweise:

- Lehnsgut ist ein als *Leh(e)n* überlassenes Anwesen (für welches Abgaben an den Grundherren fällig werden), das Gegenstück hierzu ist *Allodialgut*
- Frei-, Fron-, Bauern- und Rittergut weisen auf andere Verpflichtungen oder die Freistellung davon (z. B. wegen Verpflichtung zum Ritterdienst) hin
- Staats- und Krongut weisen den Eigentümer aus

Zusammenfassung: Landgut kommt von Landwirtschaft und damit nur indirekt von der ländlichen Gegend.

Comment: Die obige Ausführung ist eine sehr plausibel, weitere Übrlegungsrichtung: Mit "Landgut" wird also "Land[wirtschafts]gut" gemeint, wobei "Gut" für "unbewegliches Gut" (=Immobilie) steht.
Es kommt nämlich oft vor, dass bei der kumulierten Zusammensetzung von neuen Komposita (abgehend von einem schon vorhandenen Kompositum) einzelne Wortteile weggelassen werden, damit das neue zusammengesetzte Wort nicht zu lang (und daher schwerfällig, umständlich) wird.

Comment: Beispiele aus Duden: Ohrenarzt: kurz für ↑Hals-Nasen-Ohren-Arzt; Optronik: kurz für ↑Optoelektronik; Christogramm: kurz für ↑Christusmonogramm

Comment: Eine Erklärung der Wort*herkunft* sehe ich hier nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Das ist natürlich ein sehr altes Wort, es dürfte gefährlich sein, da mit Muttersprachler-Sprachgefühl ranzugehen. Entsprechend sage ich gleich, dass es durchaus sein, kann, dass ich mit meinem Verständnis falsch liege.

Was man, glaube ich, sagen kann: Das Substantiv "Gut" steht in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung für *Eigentum* oder *Besitz*, häufig zu finden in Idiomen und Komposita:

> Guthaben
> Hab und Gut
> Allgemeingut
> begütert
> gutschreiben, Gutschein
> Kulturgut, Liedgut (als "Besitz" einer Kultur)

Das ist auch die erste Bedeutung, die zum Beispiel in Wiktionary angegeben wird: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gut

Nicht weit davon weg und historisch lange die wichtigste Form von Besitz ist dann insbesondere der Besitz von Land, womit besonders landwirtschaftlich genutztes Land gemeint ist:

> Er hatte Güter in Brandenburg

Ein *Gut* oder *Landgut* steht dann entsprechend für den Hof und das Land eines Landbesitzers auf seinem Land. Das Land gehört zu dem Begriff ursprünglich mit dazu, er steht für den ganzen Betrieb und Besitz. Im engeren Sinn sind dann das Gebäude oder der Gebäudekomplex gemeint, der *Gutshof*. Die Höfe konnten auch groß werden, bis zu schlossähnlichen Anlagen mit vielen Nebengebäuden. Die etymologische Linie vermute ich aber so, dass das Wort für den Besitz im Sinn von Landbesitz sich hier spezialisiert hat von einer Bezeichnung für den gesamten Landbesitz hin zu einer Bezeichnung für die Gebäude als prägnanten Teil davon.

Comment: Danke allen für die Resonanz. Allein zum Begriff "Hof": Er war URSPRÜNGLICH nur eine von Gebäuden/Mauern umschlossene [rechteckige] Fläche. Auf ein ländliches Anwesen übertragen war also der [nach oben hin offene] Hof meistens vollständig umgeben von Wohnhaus, Scheunen, Schuppen und Stallungen. Die Anordnung der Gebäude UM DEN Hof war also sein Ur-Charakteristikum. Erst später entwickelte sich die Vorstellung des Hofes als gleichbedeutend mit dem gesamten [Land]gut, egal wie groß letzteres ist/war (pars pro toto), und sogar die Anordnung der Gebäude war nicht mehr maßgebend (s. Haufenhof).

Comment: @Lorenz Hofmann: das ist natürlich richtig. Ich habe nochmal entsprechend präzisiert -- beim Begriff "Gutshof" kann man in diesem Sinn nicht sagen, dass dieser ursprünglich für den gesamten Besitz stand.